# Find the $\lim_{x\to 1} x^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$ without applying L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

Professor wants me to find the limit

$$
\lim_{x\to 1} x^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}
$$
without using L'Hôpital and even gave the following advice:

*Rewrite the exponent as a product of sum and difference, make the following change of variables $h=\frac 1{x-1},$ when $x$ tends to $1,$ $h$ will tend to infinity. Add and subtract $1$ to the $x$ of the base and use the Euler number limit .*

---

Despite that, I was unable to find a coherent answer.

I fail to see how rewriting the exponent of $\lim_{x\to 1} x^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$ as $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}$ would help me solve this, even less so when I turn $\frac{1}{x-1} $ into $h.$

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you the fast-running substitution $u:=x^2-1\thinspace.$

Let $\thinspace x^2-1=u$ as $u\to 0$, then you have :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 1}x^{\frac 1{x^2-1}}&=\lim_{x\to 1} {\left(x^2\right)}^{\frac{1}{2(x^2-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\left(1+u\right)^{\frac 1u}\right)^{\frac 12}\\
&=e^{\frac 12}=\sqrt e\thinspace .\end{align}$$

Because, $\thinspace \lim_{u\to 0}(1+u)^{\frac 1u}=e\thinspace $ by [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Alternative_characterizations) of the number $e\thinspace .$

---

Also, using your professor's hint $u:=\frac {1}{x-1}$ as $|u|\to\infty$, you have :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 1}x^{\frac 1{x^2-1}}&=\lim_{x\to 1}x^{\frac {1}{(x-1)(x+1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(x^{\frac 1{x-1}}\right)^{\frac {1}{x+1}}\\
&=\lim_{|u|\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac 1u\right)^u\right)^{\frac {1}{2+\frac 1u}}\\
&=\sqrt e\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Because, you know that

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{u\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac 1u\right)^u&=\lim_{u\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac 1u\right)^u\\
&=e\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please do not answer "no-clue questions".https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933  Wait for the OP to show their work. Moreover, this does not follow the hint the OP was given.

Comment: @AnneBauval Well, I interpreted the *Rewrite the exponent as a product of sum and difference, make the following change of variables h=1/(x-1), when x tends to 1, h will tend to infinity. Add and subtract 1 to the x of the base and use the Euler number limit*  **as a OP's attempt.** Now, I see that, this is a different situation. Anyway, I can wait the OP's attempt.

Answer (score -4):

> using series expansion

let : $$t = x - 1 \implies t \to 0$$
$$\lim_{t\to0}\left({t＋1}\right)^{\frac {1}{(t＋1)^2-1}}＝\lim_{t\to0}(t＋1)^{\frac {1}{t^2＋2t}}＝\lim_{t\to0}e^{\frac {ln(1＋t)}{t^2＋2t}}＝\lim_{t\to0}e^{\frac {t－\frac {t^2}{2}＋O(t^2)}{t^2＋2t}}＝e^\frac{1}{2}$$

> using $$ln(1+t)=t－\frac {t^2}{2}＋O(t^2)$$

Comment: Please do not answer "no-clue questions". https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933  Wait for the OP to show their work. Moreover, this does not follow the hint the OP was given.